# como saber el peso de una string o variable en python3

Tags: python-3.x

Saben como puedo saber cuantos bytes tiene una x cadena o variable?

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa. Te dejo los siguientes enlaces para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta. [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347). De paso Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder saber cual es el peso en memoria de una variable, puedes usar `getsizeof()` que se encuentra en el paquete `sys`

```py
import sys; #importas todo lo del paquete

nombre = "SO español"
print(sys.getsizeof(nombre)) # pasas como parámetro la variable que deseas
```

**Resultado**

> 83

El cual devuelve el número de `bytes` ocupados en memoria por el objeto, esto no equivale lo que ocupa la cadena, para ello solo bastaría con `len()`, esto es solo para `str` o datos de tipo `char` :

```py
nombre = "SO español"
print(len(nombre))
```

**Resultado**

> 10

[Documentación](https://kite.com/python/docs/sys.getsizeof)